# Understanding Matlab code (indexes)

Tags: python, matlab

I've never used Matlab before and I'm trying to convert this section of code to Python but I'm not sure I really understand what is going on. Here's the code:

```
  % Calculate the price at all interior nodes
    offsetConstants = [aj(1); cj(end)];
    for i = N:-1:1
        price(2:end-1,i) = A*price(2:end-1,i+1);
        % Offset the first and last terms
        price([2 end-1],i) = price([2 end-1],i) + ...
            offsetConstants.*price([1 end],i+1);
```

So far I have been using http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html to go through it, but I'm still lost at some parts. Heres what I have so far

OffsetConstants is creating matrix with entries from aj and cj

For loop is taking price at all values except 1st and last row and multiplying it by A and then adding back in the first and last terms.

Could someone explain this to me better?

Answer (score 0):

```
offsetConstants = [aj(1); cj(end)];
```

Create vector `offsetConstants` of 2 terms. 
One is first term in `aj` and the other is last term in `cj`. You are totally correct on this.

```
for i = N:-1:1
```

The reverse style looks like you want to back-propagate the columns in `price`. 
But be careful for the range. `i+1` goes up to `N+1` and I guess the `price` matrix has that many columns.

```
    price(2:end-1,i) = A*price(2:end-1,i+1);
```

You start from column `N+1`, take the entire column except for the first and last terms, and multiply by `A`, `A` being either a scalar or a `(N+1)x(N+1)` matrix. 
Then you *store* the product into column `N`.

```
    price([2 end-1],i) = price([2 end-1],i) + ...
        offsetConstants.*price([1 end],i+1);
```

At last, you take the first and last terms of the `N+1`-th column, element-wise-multiply it by `offsetConstants`, and *add* it on to the **second and second-last** terms.

Iterate this procedure until taking column #2 and putting back into column #1.

Note: `price([2 end-1],i)` is equivalent to `[price(2,i),price(end-1,i)]` which is NOT `price(2:end-1,i)`.